# Отображение названия страницы с которой отправили форму захвата

Tags: php, html, api, form, input

Здравствуйте уважаемые разработчики и не только ;)

**Существует форма на сайте** *.html

```
    <form action="telegram.php" method="POST">
  <div class="close-form">
    <a href="№"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></a>
  </div>
  <legend class="text-mar">Оформление заказа</legend>
  <div class="form-wrap" id="form-mar">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_name" required placeholder="Имя">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_phone" required placeholder="Телефон">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_text" placeholder="Название Товара">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_color" placeholder="Цвет">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="button-form-option" class="pulse">Заказать звонок</button>
</form>
```

**И обработчик формы** *.php

```
    $name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$text = $_POST['user_text'];
$color = $_POST['user_color'];
$token = "******************************";
$chat_id = "**********";
$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Название товара' => $text,
  'Цвет' => $color,
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: thank-you.html');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

***Суть вопроса*** - *Как узнать с какой страницы отправили эту форму, т.к. таких форм на сайте ~ 20 шт.*

*Смотрел варианты как люди делают, вроде как через **$**, но я не понял как это реализовывается.*

*Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это возможно реализовать ?*

```
    <?php

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$text = $_POST['user_text'];
$color = $_POST['user_color'];
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$token = "756824975:AAETnjZgh_qViRQQ6nbkuJz4ulZzPpJH1cw";
$chat_id = "-215716646";
$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Название товара' => $text,
  'Цвет' => $color,
  'Страница' => $_SERVER,
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: thank-you.html');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']* ?

Comment: Если я это добавлю в обработчик, должно отображать ? ;)

Comment: Для начала проверьте, то ли это, что вам нужно :) Сделайте *echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];*

Comment: Вообще, для захвата с какой страницы отправился запрос, как правило ставят *UTM-метки*. Поэтому, где-то в форме можете поставить *input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="my_page"* и обрабатывать, как одну из переменных формы.

Comment: @Kosmos выдает - Array

$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Название товара' => $text,
  'Цвет' => $color,
  'Страница' => $_SERVER,
);

Comment: Без кода не понятно. Приведенный вами код в вопросе и комментарии не соответствует друг другу, что вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: $arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Название товара' => $text,
  'Цвет' => $color,
  'Страница' => $_SERVER, // Добавленное поле
);


$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$text = $_POST['user_text'];
$color = $_POST['user_color'];
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // Добавленное поле

Comment: а почему передали *$_SERVER*, когда речь идет о значении $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']? Переменная $_SERVER - это массив.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84619/discussion-between-nick-and-kosmos).

Answer (score 0):

- 1-й способ: 
  Добавить в массив строку - 'Страница' =>    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
- 2-й способ:   Добавить Hidden поле в каждую из форм, присвоить name и
  value, внести данные для отправки в массив

**Огромная благодарность https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192199/kosmos**