# узнать на php c какой формы ее класс пришел ajax запрос?

Tags: php

```
$(".form-comebacker").submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST"
        , url: "form.php"
        , data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function () {
        $(".form-comebacker")[0].reset();
        $(".message-send-ok").addClass("active");
         console.log("да");
    });
    return false;
});
           $(".form-consultation").submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST"
        , url: "form.php"
        , data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function () {
        $(".form-comebacker")[0].reset();
        $(".message-send-ok").addClass("active");
         console.log("да");
    });
    return false;
});




 <?php 
/* Здесь проверяется существование переменных */ 
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];} 



/* Сюда впишите свою эл. почту */ 
$address1 = "@mail.ru"; 

/* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */ 
$mes1 = "1 собщение  \nТелефон: $phone"; 
$mes2 = "2 собщение  \nТелефон: $phone"; 
Еди запрос c .form-comebacker 1 собщение 
Еди запрос c .form-consultation 2 собщение 

/* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */ 
$sub='Заявка!'; //сабж 
$email=' <Roistat>'; // от кого 
$send = mail ($address1,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email"); 
?>
```

узнать на php c какой формы ее класс пришел ajax запрос?
ели с классом class_1 оправить 1 собщение, если class_2 - второе

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните вопрос примерами кода, от куда и куда что отправляется, и как обрабатывается в php

Comment: Ну так добавьте на форму скрытое поле с каким нибудь значением и проверяйте.

Comment: не понял как,напишите пример пожалуйста

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/894749/Отображение-названия-страницы-с-которой-отправили-форму-захвата

Comment: как это написать на php ? Еди запрос c .form-comebacker 1 собщение 
Еди запрос c .form-consultation 2 собщение